# Não consigo cadastrar datas

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu tenho um Form com duas datas, porém, quando vou cadastrá-las me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.

O que pode ser?

Essa aplicação é feita em quatro camadas:

1. A camada `modelos` é onde fica a classe
2. A camada `DAL` é onde fica o código da conexão com o banco
3. A camada `BLL` é onde fica o código da regra de negócio
4. camada `UIWindows` é onde fica o código dos botões do form.

### Camada Modelos:

```
namespace Biblioteca.Modelos
{
public class ExemplarModelos
{
    private int _idExemplar;

    public int IdExemplar
    {
        get { return _idExemplar; }
        set { _idExemplar = value; }
    }



    private int _codigoObra;

    public int CodigoObra
    {
        get { return _codigoObra; }
        set { _codigoObra = value; }
    }



    private string _subTituloExemplar;

    public string SubTituloExemplar
    {
        get { return _subTituloExemplar; }
        set { _subTituloExemplar = value; }
    }



    private int _codigoVolExemplar;

    public int CodigoVolExemplar
    {
        get { return _codigoVolExemplar; }
        set { _codigoVolExemplar = value; }
    }



    private int _numExemplar;

    public int NumExemplar
    {
        get { return _numExemplar; }
        set { _numExemplar = value; }
    }



    private int _numTomboExemplar;

    public int NumTomboExemplar
    {
        get { return _numTomboExemplar; }
        set { _numTomboExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _numEdicaoExemplar;

    public string NumEdicaoExemplar
    {
        get { return _numEdicaoExemplar; }
        set { _numEdicaoExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _anoEdicaoExemplar;

    public string AnoEdicaoExemplar
    {
        get { return _anoEdicaoExemplar; }
        set { _anoEdicaoExemplar = value; }
    }



    private int _numPagsExemplar;

    public int NumPagsExemplar
    {
        get { return _numPagsExemplar; }
        set { _numPagsExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _permissaoEmprestimo;

    public string PermissaoEmprestimo
    {
        get { return _permissaoEmprestimo; }
        set { _permissaoEmprestimo = value; }
    }



    private DateTime _dataEntradaExemplar;

    public DateTime DataEntradaExemplar
    {
        get { return _dataEntradaExemplar; }
        set { _dataEntradaExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _tipoPeriodicidadeExemplar;

    public string TipoPeriodicidadeExemplar
    {
        get { return _tipoPeriodicidadeExemplar; }
        set { _tipoPeriodicidadeExemplar = value; }
    }



    private DateTime _dataHemerotecaExemplar;

    public DateTime DataHemerotecaExemplar
    {
        get { return _dataHemerotecaExemplar; }
        set { _dataHemerotecaExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _tipoSerieOuColecao;

    public string TipoSerieOuColecao
    {
        get { return _tipoSerieOuColecao; }
        set { _tipoSerieOuColecao = value; }
    }



    private string _descSerieOuColecao;

    public string DescSerieOuColecao
    {
        get { return _descSerieOuColecao; }
        set { _descSerieOuColecao = value; }
    }




    private string _localizacaoExemplar;

    public string LocalizacaoExemplar
    {
        get { return _localizacaoExemplar; }
        set { _localizacaoExemplar = value; }
    }



    private string _codigoIsbn;

    public string CodigoIsbn
    {
        get { return _codigoIsbn; }
        set { _codigoIsbn = value; }
    }




    private int _codigoEdi;

    public int CodigoEdi
    {
        get { return _codigoEdi; }
        set { _codigoEdi = value; }
    }


    private string _codigoCdd;

    public string CodigoCdd
    {
        get { return _codigoCdd; }
        set { _codigoCdd = value; }
    }

}

}
```

### Camada DAL:

```
namespace Biblioteca.DAL
{
public class ExemplarDAL
{
    public void Incluir_exemplar(ExemplarModelos exemplar)
    {
        //conexão
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlTransaction t = null;

        try
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = Dados.StringDeConexao;

            //command                      
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = cn;

            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Exemplar
            (CD_OBRA, DS_SUBTITULO, CD_VOLUME, NR_EXEMPLAR, NR_TOMBO, NR_EDICAO, ANO_EDICAO, NR_PAGINAS, LG_EMPRESTIMO, DT_ENTRADA, " +
             "TP_PERIODICIDADE, DT_HEMEROTECA, TP_SERIECOL, DS_SERIECOL, DS_LOCALIZACAO, CD_ISBN, CD_EDITORA, CD_CDD) VALUES (@CD_OBRA, " +
             "@DS_SUBTITULO, @CD_VOLUME, @NR_EXEMPLAR, @NR_TOMBO, @NR_EDICAO, @ANO_EDICAO, @NR_PAGINAS, @LG_EMPRESTIMO, @DT_ENTRADA, " +
             "@TP_PERIODICIDADE, @DT_HEMEROTECA, @TP_SERIECOL, @DS_SERIECOL, @DS_LOCALIZACAO, @CD_ISBN, @CD_EDITORA, @CD_CDD);select @@IDENTITY;";

            //command Obra
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

            cmd2.Connection = cn;

            cmd2.CommandText = @"SELECT CD_OBRA FROM Obra";

            //command Editora
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();

            cmd3.Connection = cn;

            cmd3.CommandText = @"SELECT CD_EDITORA FROM Editora";

            //command Cdd
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();

            cmd4.Connection = cn;

            cmd4.CommandText = @"SELECT CD_CDD FROM Cdd";

            cn.Open();

            t = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);//default

            cmd.Transaction = t;

            cmd2.Transaction = t;

            cmd3.Transaction = t;

            cmd4.Transaction = t;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_OBRA", exemplar.CodigoObra);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DS_SUBTITULO", exemplar.SubTituloExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_VOLUME", exemplar.CodigoVolExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_EXEMPLAR", exemplar.NumExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_TOMBO", exemplar.NumTomboExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_EDICAO", exemplar.NumEdicaoExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANO_EDICAO", exemplar.AnoEdicaoExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_PAGINAS", exemplar.NumPagsExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LG_EMPRESTIMO", exemplar.PermissaoEmprestimo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_ENTRADA", exemplar.DataEntradaExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP_PERIODICIDADE", exemplar.TipoPeriodicidadeExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_HEMEROTECA", exemplar.DataHemerotecaExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP_SERIECOL", exemplar.TipoSerieOuColecao);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DS_SERIECOL", exemplar.DescSerieOuColecao);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DS_LOCALIZACAO", exemplar.LocalizacaoExemplar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_ISBN", exemplar.CodigoIsbn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_EDITORA", exemplar.CodigoEdi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_CDD", exemplar.CodigoCdd);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_OBRA", exemplar.CodigoObra);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_EDITORA", exemplar.CodigoEdi);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_CDD", exemplar.CodigoCdd);

            exemplar.IdExemplar = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

            t.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            t.Rollback();
            throw new Exception("Servidor no Servidor:" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

}

}
```

### Camada BLL:

```
namespace Biblioteca.BLL
{
public class ExemplarBLL
{


    public void Incluir_exemplar(ExemplarModelos exemplar)
    {
        ExemplarDAL obj = new ExemplarDAL();
        obj.Incluir_exemplar(exemplar);
    }
}

}
```

### Camada UIWindows:

```
namespace UIWindows
{
public partial class ExemplarForm : Form
{
    public ExemplarForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void bt_incluir_exe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
            try
            {
                ExemplarModelos exemplar = new ExemplarModelos();

                exemplar.CodigoObra = (int)comboBoxCodigoObra.SelectedValue;
                exemplar.SubTituloExemplar = textBoxSubTituloExe.Text;
                exemplar.CodigoVolExemplar = int.Parse(textBoxVolumeExe.Text);
                exemplar.NumExemplar = int.Parse(textBoxNumExe.Text);
                exemplar.NumTomboExemplar = int.Parse(textBoxNumTomboExe.Text);
                exemplar.NumEdicaoExemplar = textBoxNumEdicaoExe.Text;
                exemplar.AnoEdicaoExemplar = textBoxAnoEdicaoExe.Text;
                exemplar.NumPagsExemplar = int.Parse(textBoxNumPaginasExe.Text);
                exemplar.PermissaoEmprestimo = CBPermissaoEmprestimoExe.Text;

                exemplar.DataEntradaExemplar = Convert.ToDateTime(maskedTextBoxDataEntradaExe.Text);

                exemplar.TipoPeriodicidadeExemplar = CBTipoPeriodicidade.Text;

                exemplar.DataHemerotecaExemplar = Convert.ToDateTime(maskedTextBoxDataHemerotecaExe.Text);

                exemplar.TipoSerieOuColecao = CBSerieColecaoExe.Text;
                exemplar.DescSerieOuColecao = textBoxDescSerieOuColecaoExe.Text;
                exemplar.LocalizacaoExemplar = textBoxLocalizacaoExe.Text;
                exemplar.CodigoIsbn = textBoxIsbnExe.Text;
                exemplar.CodigoEdi = (int)comboBoxCodigoEditoraExe.SelectedValue;
                exemplar.CodigoCdd = Convert.ToString(comboBoxCodCdd.SelectedValue);

                ExemplarBLL obj = new ExemplarBLL();

                obj.Incluir_exemplar(exemplar);

                MessageBox.Show("O exemplar foi incluído com sucesso!");

                textBoxIDExe.Text = Convert.ToString(exemplar.IdExemplar);

                AtualizaGridExemplar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }  
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Lucas adicione na sua pergunta o seu código, por favor

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado Virgilio, vou postar.

Comment: A data que vem do formulário está chegando no back-end? 
Verifique se ela não está chegando nula ou em formato incorreto.

Comment: O cara obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui solucionar, o problema estava nesse trecho da camada DAL, a solução ficou assim:      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_ENTRADA", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = exemplar.DataEntradaExemplar;

Comment: @LucasBarbosaFonseca Seria bom se tu postasse a sua resolução como uma resposta para sua pergunta para que o próximo que tiver essa duvida possa ser ajudado mais facilmente :)

Comment: Opa, vou colocar, obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal, eu consegui solucionar esse problema, ele estava na camada DAL,
os trechos seguintes estavam errados:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_ENTRADA", exemplar.DataEntradaExemplar);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_HEMEROTECA", exemplar.DataHemerotecaExemplar);
```

A solução desses problemas ficaram assim:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_ENTRADA", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = exemplar.DataEntradaExemplar;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_HEMEROTECA", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = exemplar.DataHemerotecaExemplar;
```

Abraço.